# Steps to execute .ear file from Glassfish server into Tomee+ server

Tags: netbeans-7.1, apache-tomee

As a newbie to Enterprise Applications I'm trying to get it done.

I developed an Enterprise application in Netbeans 7.1.2. It runs successfully using the default Glassfish server. With the need to change the server, I downloaded and installed Tomee+ server, and made some changes to make Tomee Manager Interface work on my system. 
I deployed the .ear file (Glassfish server output) into Tomee+ by placing it in the Tomee webapps folder, with the server in the running state. It gets automatically deployed and appears in the Tomcat Web Application Manager interface.

Then, by providing the suitable path in the address bar, like `http://localhost:8080/app-war/faces/app.xhtml`, it provides the frontend screen but the backend process is not working if I click the submit button. Instead, it simply provides a status page, like `HTTP Status 500 - javax.el.ELException: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction was rolled back, presumably because setRollbackOnly was called during a synchronization`.

**My question is**: what went wrong with the steps I took for deploying it in Tomee+ server?

Answer (score 0):

no more verbose stack?

btw can you try to:
1) check you have in tomee.xml the line 
2) put your ear in /apps/ instead of webapps/

The point is by default (can be configured with the snapshot/next release) tomee extracts the ear in a folder simply removing the extension (webapps/your-ear/ for instance) and then tomcat takes this folder as a webapp so your deployment is no more the one expected. That's why moving it over a folder not managed by tomcat (apps) is often enough.

That's said, Glassfish transaction management is sometimes too tolerant (why i ask the full stack you got).